# how to use multiple filter using OR conditon in java 8

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8

how to use multiple filter using OR conditon in java 8

```
return getAllData().stream()
            .filter(emp -> emp.getEmpName().equals(empName) && emp->emp.getEmpEmailId().equals(empEmailId))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

i've tried this butnits not accepting my .getEmailId()

can anyone please help

Comment: you mean `|| emp.getEmpEmailId().equals(empEmailId)` ? no need to use `emp->` in the second part of the condition.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution will be to use the simple 'or' expression:

```
@Test
void test() {
    var allData = List.of(
        new Employee("john", "a@b.c"),
        new Employee("doe", "a@b.c"),
        new Employee("jane", "x@y.z")
    );

    var filtered = allData.stream()
        .filter(emp ->  "jane".equals(emp.empName()) || "x@y.z".equals(emp.empName()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

If the filtering criteria is describing something specific about this `employee`, you can encapsulate it inside the class, like this:

```
record Employee (String empName, String empEmailId) {
    private boolean hasNameOrEmail(String name, String email) {
        return name.equals(this.empName) || email.equals(this.empEmailId);
    }
}

@Test
void test() {
    // ...
    var filtered = allData.stream()
        .filter(emp -> emp.hasNameOrEmail("jane", "x@y.z"))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Lastly, if you want to create something more generic, you can declare different `Predicate` objects that can be chained with `.or()` :

```
public Predicate<Employee> hasName(String lookingFor) {
    return emp -> lookingFor.equals(emp.empName());
}
public Predicate<Employee> hasEmail(String lookingFor) {
    return emp -> lookingFor.equals(emp.empEmailId());
}

@Test
void test() {
    // ...      
    var filtered = allData.stream()
        .filter(hasName("jane").or(hasEmail("x@y.z")))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```